# Change DefaulServiceVersion for Azure Blob Storage with PHP/LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, azure, api, sdk

Any chance someone knowing how to set the [blob service properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/set-blob-service-properties)  via php/laravel? I've seen answers on C# where they use their integrated SDK. I tried that but I can't get started as there is little to 0 info on how to use the azure PHP SDK for Laravel or I don't get it.

What I've tried and failed:

```
 $date = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T');
    $account_name = "**************";
    $containername = "media";
    $access_key = "access_key_from_portal";

    $canonicalizedHeaders  = "x-ms-date:$date\nx-ms-version:2017-11-09";
    // $canonicalizedResource = "/$account_name/$containername\ncomp:list\nrestype:container";
    // $canonicalizedResource = "/$account_name\nrestype:service\ncomp:properties";
    $canonicalizedResource = "/$account_name /$containername\ncomp:metadata\nrestype:container\ntimeout:20";



    $arraysign = array();
    $arraysign[] = 'PUT';                     /*HTTP Verb*/
    $arraysign[] = '';                        /*Content-Encoding*/
    $arraysign[] = '';                        /*Content-Language*/
    $arraysign[] = '';                        /*Content-Length (include value when zero)*/
    $arraysign[] = '';                        /*Content-MD5*/
    $arraysign[] = '';                        /*Content-Type*/
    $arraysign[] = '';                        /*Date*/
    $arraysign[] = '';                        /*If-Modified-Since */
    $arraysign[] = '';                        /*If-Match*/
    $arraysign[] = '';                        /*If-None-Match*/
    $arraysign[] = '';                        /*If-Unmodified-Since*/
    $arraysign[] = '';                        /*Range*/
    $arraysign[] = $canonicalizedHeaders;     /*CanonicalizedHeaders*/
    $arraysign[] = $canonicalizedResource;    /*CanonicalizedResource*/

    $stringtosign = implode("\n", $arraysign);
    $signature = 'SharedKey' . ' ' . $account_name . ':' . base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', utf8_encode($stringtosign), base64_decode($access_key)));
    $endpoint = 'https://' . $account_name . '.blob.core.windows.net';
    // $endpoint = 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/df4efeca-7f1e-44cd-b037-5ced337b68b0/resourceGroups/PiHealthcare/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/preceptorshipblobstorage?api-version=2019-06-01';

    $url = $endpoint . '/' . '?restype=service&comp=properties';

    $headers = [
        "Content-Length:0",
        "x-ms-date:{$date}",
        'x-ms-version:2017-11-09',
        'Accept:application/json;odata=nometadata',
        "Authorization:{$signature}"
    ];



    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response  = curl_exec($ch);
    echo curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($response);
    echo '<hr>';
    print_r($signature);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($date);
    echo '<hr>';
    print_r($stringtosign);
    echo '<hr>';
    print_r($canonicalizedHeaders);
```

I keep getting the same error:
*the mac signature found in the http request is not the same as any computed signature*

I guess I don't encode the ShareKey in proper way?

Someone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set blob service properties in PHP application, you can use [Azure storage PHP SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/tree/1afd50bb3f89f1fed9de0b1edaf424f37a4bc13a) to implement it.

For example

```
   $connectionString = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<yourAccount>;AccountKey=<yourKey>';
    $blobClient = BlobRestProxy::createBlobService($connectionString);
    echo "Get Blob Service properties" . PHP_EOL;
    $originalProperties = $blobClient->getServiceProperties();
    // Set blob service properties
    echo "Set Blob Service properties" . PHP_EOL;
    $retentionPolicy = new RetentionPolicy();
    $retentionPolicy->setEnabled(true);
    $retentionPolicy->setDays(10);

    $logging = new Logging();
    $logging->setRetentionPolicy($retentionPolicy);
    $logging->setVersion('1.0');
    $logging->setDelete(true);
    $logging->setRead(true);
    $logging->setWrite(true);

    $metrics = new Metrics();
    $metrics->setRetentionPolicy($retentionPolicy);
    $metrics->setVersion('1.0');
    $metrics->setEnabled(true);
    $metrics->setIncludeAPIs(true);
    $serviceProperties = new ServiceProperties();
    $serviceProperties->setLogging($logging);
    $serviceProperties->setHourMetrics($metrics);
    $blobClient->setServiceProperties($serviceProperties);

    // revert back to original properties
    echo "Revert back to original service properties" . PHP_EOL;
    $blobClient->setServiceProperties($originalProperties->getValue());
    echo "Service properties sample completed" . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I am calling this code from my web routes as a Get Method with the code inside a controller. Not sure if that's the correct way of doing it as it requires a PUT request?